# Could a rogue planet support life?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, rogue-planets, astrophysics

I was wondering whether a free floating planet could potentially host life. If so, how? I was thinking of a geothermically active planet, where the only source of heat comes within the planet itself. But then, there wouldn't be any source of light since it wouldn't be gravitationally bound to any star. I also imagine a thick atmosphere resulting from the activity of the planet itself. Could life as we know it really arise from such harsh conditions?

Comment: Hi. Just to be clear, when you say life as we know it, do you mean "hairy bipeds with smartphones" or just something we would recognise as "life"?

Comment: Lol, what I meant is something that could resemble life at its primordial stages on Earth (Archea). But yeah, I guess it could eventually evolve in the right conditions.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Liam.  "This is my first time on this forum, so tell me if I am missing anything before I can ask a question."  This is one of the many uses for the Sandbox.  A great place to propose questions and get help formatting them.  https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: There are already quite a few questions along these lines, try https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=rogue+planet+life and see if any of them answer your question. If not then please edit yours to show how it is different and we can look to open it and provide an answer.

Comment: Light is not a requirement for life